# has-error with ngClass on load even the expression is false it loads the class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

Trying to load boot strap has-error class using  ng-class with condition on a variable injected to controller from my factory ,though the initial value of variable is false , the has-error loads up and my fields are shown to have error

html :

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error' : variable.var1 }">
```

{{var1}} - printing this expression to see the value on the view

when the app loads {{var1}} shows as false on view

yet has-error is active and my input fields are highlighted in red

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('SpicyController', ['$scope','factroy1' function($scope,factroy1) {

     $scope.variable = factroy1;    


    };


}]);

myApp.factory('factroy1',function(){

    var variable={}
    variable.var1=false;

    return variable;

});
```

Comment: using ng-class like this in html                                                                       <div ng-class="{'has-error' : variable.var1}">

Comment: Can you create a fiddle reproducing the behavior?

Comment: seems ok here http://codepen.io/maio/pen/ZbdxwR

Comment: Intresting .. Yeah it works in your demo maioman .. but somehow it is breaking in my application though .. that is making me strange .. when I run in my application with a negation symbol .. I mean  ! variable.var1 the initial state looks fine

Answer (score 1):

My aboslute mistake in my code quoted false as  a string "false"  that killed me